# Orientation issue after Video dismissed: Cordova 2.1.0 + iOS 6

Tags: html, cordova, video, ios6, orientation-changes

I'm building a Phonegap app that needs to play fullscreen html5 videos.

My problem is that with Phonegap 2.1.0 and iOS 6 something changed with orientation, and everytime I dismiss a fullscreen video (press the done button), the video forces my app in portrait mode even though the App is locked in landscape mode.

I am not doing any obj-c magic here, it's a standard html5 video tag.

```
<video id="myvideo" src="goat.mp4" controls="" autobuffer=""></video>
```

I assume it's the video layer on top of my viewController that forces the orientation change, but how do I make it stop?

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated! Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For PhoneGap 2.1, check out the [bug fix](https://github.com/apache/incubator-cordova-ios/commit/681016b3e0e7e006657406fc0158aaa8515c3369)

In "MainViewController.m" change `viewWillAppear` to

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
  // Set the main view to utilize the entire application frame space of the device.
  // Change this to suit your view's UI footprint needs in your application.

  UIView* rootView =[[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow] rootViewController] view];
  CGRect webViewFrame = [[[rootView subviews] objectAtIndex:0] frame];  // first subview is the UIWebView
  if (CGRectEqualToRect(webViewFrame, CGRectZero)) { // UIWebView is sized according to its parent, here it hasn't been sized yet
      self.view.frame = [[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame]; // size UIWebView's parent according to application frame, which will in turn resize the UIWebView
  }

  [super viewWillAppear:animated];
}
```

Comment: Any idea if this is fixed in 2.2?

Comment: As far as I know, the problem has been fixed in the latest version.

Comment: I'm having a similar orientation problem with iOS 6.1 and video: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14687731/are-html5-video-tags-be-broken-in-ios-6-1-apps-using-uiwebview-phonegap