# Are HTML5 <video> tags be broken in iOS 6.1 apps using UIWebView (PhoneGap)?

Tags: ios, cordova, uiwebview

We have a PhoneGap application that uses HTML5 video tags. If you click the "Done" button while a video is playing, the video stops, but the video element shows a double preview image: One in the background, which is rotated 90º and one in the foreground that is the correct orientation.

Has anyone else experienced this and do you know of a workaround?

[image]

Comment: Updated to iOS 6.1.3 and still getting this problem. Does anyone know if this is related to PhoneGap or iOS UIWebView?

Comment: Another thing to note is that this ONLY happens when the "Done" button is clicked before the video ends.